# Firebase Admin SDK with Cloud functions for cloud storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to use the fire base admin SDK with cloud storage so I can upload images from the server side. For some reason when I type in admin.storage() my functions refuse to upload. I have everything set up well but for some reason that's the only thing that is not working.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. --- It would also be good to see what exactly "my functions refuse to upload" means. Do you get an error message?

Comment: No, it just does not deploy when I di "firebase deploy." It says there was an error parsing my code. I moved the admin.storage() inside the function instead of declaring within my admin.js file and it works. But now I am having problems with .upload(). Hopefully that is a different issue.

Comment: Did you see the first part of my comment too? --- I'd also recommend re-reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as right now there's not enough for us to figure out what's going on (well, not for me at least - maybe somebody else spots it).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deploy your code on Firebase Cloud Functions by making some adjustments. If I'm not mistaken the error you encountered is:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers. Please ensure that admin.js only exports cloud functions.
```

The error is saying that you can only export functions. You cannot export declarations such as `const`.

ES modules support only several syntax variations in order to be statically analyzed.
According to [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#syntax) documentation, the variations are:

```
// Exporting individual features
export let name1, name2, …, nameN; // also var, const
export let name1 = …, name2 = …, …, nameN; // also var, const
export function functionName(){...}
export class ClassName {...}

// Export list
export { name1, name2, …, nameN };

// Renaming exports
export { variable1 as name1, variable2 as name2, …, nameN };

// Exporting destructured assignments with renaming
export const { name1, name2: bar } = o;

// Default exports
export default expression;
export default function (…) { … } // also class, function*
export default function name1(…) { … } // also class, function*
export { name1 as default, … };

// Aggregating modules
export * from …; // does not set the default export
export * as name1 from …; // ECMAScript® 2O20
export { name1, name2, …, nameN } from …;
export { import1 as name1, import2 as name2, …, nameN } from …;
export { default, … } from …;
```

`export foo` is not among them. It is not supported and cannot be used.

---

You can fix the error by removing `firebase-admin` on `admin.js`.

Create a new `js` file. For this instance, I used `test.js`. Refer to the below code:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

module.exports = {
    admin
};
```

On your `admin.js`:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const {admin} = require("./test");

const db = admin.firestore();
const firestore = admin.firestore;
const auth = admin.auth();
const storage = admin.storage().bucket();

module.exports = {
    db,
    firestore,
    auth,
    storage
};
```

---

For uploading objects to Google Cloud Storage, add the target Bucket on the newly created `js`:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(
    {
        storageBucket: "bucket-name"
    }
);

module.exports = {
    admin
};
```

Then on your `admin.js`, refer on below code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const {admin} = require("./test");

const db = admin.firestore();
const firestore = admin.firestore;
const auth = admin.auth();
const storage = admin.storage().bucket();

// Uploads object to Google Cloud Storage
storage.upload(filePath, {
    destination: destFileName,
  }).then(data => {
    console.log('upload success');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('error uploading to storage', err);
});

module.exports = {
    db,
    firestore,
    auth,
    storage
};
```

You may also check [Upload an object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-upload-file#storage_upload_file-nodejs) documentation for more information.

Comment: So my local path to my image is "/Users/juliancstro/Downloads/IMG_0713.jpg" is that what I input for filePath? what do I do with the string

Comment: @JulianCastro Yes, if that's the correct path to your file. and `destFileName` is the path and filename in your destination bucket. e.g. `/test_folder/test.jpg`. `IMG_0713.jpg` will be uploaded to your bucket as `/test_folder/test.jpg`.

Comment: similar to storage.upload , what is equavent of storage.download ?